# Tabla con número de columnas variable en PyLaTeX

Tags: python, python-2.7, latex

Este es el código de pruebas que utilizo para conectar a la base de datos, sacar algunos datos y escribir en una tabla los mismos:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import psycopg2
import pylatex as pl

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='xxxxx' user='xxxxx' 
           host='xxxxx.com' password='xxxx'")
    print "Estoy dentro de la base de datos"

    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("""SELECT fechor,pedido, estado
                   FROM client.ordenes_de_venta_completo
                   LIMIT 10""")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    doc = Document('basic')
    header = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
    with doc.create(pl.Section('Ultimos 10 productos')):
        with doc.create(pl.Tabular('ccc')) as table:
            table.add_hline()  
            table.add_row(header[0], header[1], header[2])
            table.add_hline()
            for row in df.index:
                table.add_row(list(df.loc[row,:]))
            table.add_hline()
    doc.generate_pdf(clean_tex=False)

 except:
    print "No puedo conectar a la base de datos"
```

El problema está al crear la cabecera de la tabla. Me gustaría sustituir esta línea:

```
table.add_row(header[0], header[1], header[2])
```

por:

```
table.add_row(column_name for column_name in header)
```

ya que cuando la query de PostgreSQL varíe, el número de campos no debe ser necesariamente 3 y la tabla por tanto puede tener un número diferente de columnas.

El problema es que al hacer esto se produce el siguiente error:

> TableRowSizeError: Number of cells added to table (0) did not match table width (3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces `table.add_row(column_name for column_name in header)` le estas pasando **un generador** a la función como único argumento. Puedes pasarle directamente la lista:

```
table.add_row(header)
```

O en todo caso desempaquetarla con `*`, lo que equivale a pasar cada uno de los elementos de la misma como argumentos individuales a la función:

```
table.add_row(*header)
```

Como debes especificar la estructura de la tabla (y el número de columnas) en el constructor de `pylatex.Tabular`, debes crear el argumento `table_spec` de forma dinámica. Si solo quieres columnas centradas puedes hacer simplemente:

```
tab_spec =  "c" * len(header)
with doc.create(pl.Section('Ultimos 10 productos')):
    with doc.create(pl.Tabular(tab_spec)) as table:
        table.add_hline()  
        table.add_row(header)
        table.add_hline()
```

Comment: Ha funcionado. No entiendo por qué antes no funcionaba al pasarle directamente la lista, pero ahora lo hace.